# I want to rename files containing spaces, hyphens etc

Tags: windows, batch

I want to rename files in some directories, and so far i have been using this:

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern= "
Set "Replace=_"

For %%a in (*.pdf,*.docx,*.xlsx,*.csv,*.doc,*.jpg,*.png,*.xlsm,*.ppt,*pptx) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)

Exit
```

I want to have multiple "Patterns" which includes space and hyphens to be "Replaced". How do I add the additional 'underscore' in "Pattern="?

Comment: Maybe switch to PowerShell? Makes things easier :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can assign 1 value to a variable. so I would create another variable with the name pattern2 for example and pass another rename command in the end using pattern2. like this

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern= "
Set "Pattern2=-"
Set "Pattern3=_-"
Set "Pattern4=-_"
Set "Pattern5=- "
Set "Pattern6= -"
Set "Pattern7=__"
Set "Replace=_"

For %%a in (*.pdf,*.docx,*.xlsx,*.csv,*.doc,*.jpg,*.png,*.xlsm,*.ppt,*pptx) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern2%=%Replace%!"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern3%=%Replace%!"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern4%=%Replace%!"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern5%=%Replace%!"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern6%=%Replace%!"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern7%=%Replace%!"
)

Exit
```

Comment: This would not work if the file had both spaces and hyphens, as after the first rename it would not have the same name as %%a anymore.

Comment: Ok, I understood what you want. I edited my answer after testing this code myself on my own files. Maybe it's not the best way to write it but it gives you the result you are seeking. and if you have a lot of combinations just run this code 3 or 4 times. the end result will probably be what you want.